# Actionscript is there a way to upload file straight into memory?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm looking into uploading an XML file and then storing it's contents in database. It looks like [upload method of flash.net.FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#upload%28%29) would do the job however it just gives you an option to upload it to server.

I could upload it to server, read it from that server and then delete that file but I would like to avoid extra work.

Is there a way to just load a file into memory without saving it on some remote location?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do exactly. Do you just want to load an XML file? If that's the case, you should use `URLLoader`. Or do you want to load a user selected file into memory? Then use `FileReference` together with `load()`

Comment: I would like to upload an XML file from user's machine.

Comment: When you say upload, it sounds like you are trying to send it to a server. You simply want to load a user selected file into memory? See my previous comment.

Comment: OH my bad.  I'm new to Flash so I still thinking that I need to send XML data to server in order to work in it in ActionScript. What I can do is just use load() which will load it into memory.  I'll try it out. Thank you for clearing it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to have the user select an XML file from their local machine, after your `myFileReference.load()`, in your `Event.COMPLETE` handler function you can use `var myXML:XML = XML(myFileReference.data);` to get the data of the file you selected.

Answer (score 1):

No this cannot be done, uploads can only be done to a server, probably for security reason.

If you need to store the content to a database anyway, why don't you make the server-side bakend handle it?

If this is just some data that you need then throw away after the program is complete, perhaps you could consider asking the user to copy and paste their data to some textfield. That might depend on your target audience thought: IT-types - no problem, non-IT types-problem :D

Comment: It was my confusion. Newbie mistake/brain fart. For some reason I thought I needed to upload the data in order to work on it in ActionScript. Yes, I'm doing exactly what you suggesting. Loading it using load() method then calling a PHP page that stores that data in databse. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can load all content in to cache, just push it into an array, when ever you want it just call it out.